# Problem passing Tuple to MySQLdb in python

Tags: python, tuples, mysql-python

I have some sql queries that work through python mysqldb to my mysql database, but i want to make them a little less sql-injection vulnerable so little bobby tables doesn't try to add data..

for example:

**ORIGINAL:**
 (This works, so ListID etc is definitely valid)

```
sql="SELECT NAME FROM ListsTable WHERE ID=%s"%(ListID)  
c.execute(sql)
```

**ATTEMPTED WITH TUPLE:**

```
sql="SELECT NAME FROM ListsTable WHERE ID=%s"  
c.execute(sql,(ListID,))
```

**WORKS:**

```
sql="SELECT NAME FROM ListsTable WHERE ID=%s"  
c.execute(sql, ListID)
```

I don't know why that 2nd attempt doesn't work as a tuple but accepts it as a single parameter, but either way for another statement i need to pass multiple parameters so this won't work for that:

**ORIGINAL:**

```
sql="SELECT * FROM ListsTable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %s,%s"%(Page, (Page*20)+20)  
c.execute(sql)
```

which works, but then this doesn't, again if i try to send the parameters as a tuple:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM ListsTable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %s,%s"  
var1=Page  
var2=(Page*20)+20  
params=(var1,var2)              
c.execute(sql,params)
```

or even just

```
sql="SELECT * FROM ListsTable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %s,%s"  
c.execute(sql,(Page,(Page*20)+20))
```

I've recently got this error on my webserver log, though note this MAY be a redherring due to the many different things I've been trying as it hasn't errored before: (The error refers to the above attempt of passing the "params" variable)

```
File "process.py", line 98, in main  
c.execute(sql,params)  
File "/var/www/cgi-bin/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute  
query = query % db.literal(args)  
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

EDIT: in case it helps, i'm using mysqldb version 1.2.3, in case it didn't accept tuples at that version, but don't get me started on how rubbish the mysqldb docs are..

Comment: It would help enormously if you gave more information than "doesn't work" in the first few cases, and showed what you were executing when you got that logged error. Please note that you can and should experiment around your problems at the Python interactive prompt (`>>>`) and/or in very simple scripts that you can run at your shell command-line -- avoid irrelevancies like your web server which make debugging simple problems harder. Show your data e.g. `print repr(ListID)`.

Comment: It all works fine in the code above, I don't get why it's such an issue to move it from string substitution to tuple parameterisation when the docs say it only accepts tuples. I would've thought that'd be an easy error to spot for anyone who isn't me. It's part of a CGI script that reads and returns JSON structures to an Android Phone so installing a local apache webserver and adapting inputs just to debug something that is probably very obvious might be counterproductive, especially as the actual script but for this is finished. Also, when the first lot don't work there is no error.

Comment: As I said, all of that CGI/JSON/Android/apache stuff is quite irrelevant to your alleged problem with MySQLdb. I certainly wasn't inciting you to install a local apache webserver, but to do some experiments that do relate to your problem, as @jsw has done. """when the first lot don't work, there is no error""" so what does "don't work" mean exactly? If you can't reproduce your problem in a manner similar to that of @jsw, you'll need to log (1) your sql statement (2) the argument tuple (3) the fetchall() result (in each case using `repr()` to avoid ambiguity) and show us the results.

Comment: Hi, yeah I get what you mean (and sorry i wasn't being rude, i do appreciate your time!), I just thought I'd have to install a local MySQL server or something to test it properly? I can definitely do that, I just made the (Perhaps wrong) assumption that the problem was something simple I've done that wouldn't require a lot of investigation. The parameters, database, sql query etc all works fine, the only different being made is the argument as a tuple (even as a single parameter it works, but not as a single-element tuple)

Answer (score 3):

Your version of mysqldb must be the problem.

http://mysql-python.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/mysql-python/MySQLdb-2.0/file/5a7c30cd9de2/MySQLdb/cursors.py#l180

was changed to:

```
1.51 -        if args is not None:
1.52 -            query = query % self.connection.literal(args)
1.53          try:
1.54 +            if args is not None:
1.55 +                query = query % tuple(map(self.connection.literal, args))
```

http://mysql-python.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/mysql-python/MySQLdb-2.0/diff/98d968f5af11/MySQLdb/cursors.py

Which is later changed to:

```
1.144 -                query = query % tuple(map(self.connection.literal, args))
1.145 +                query = query % tuple(( get_codec(a, self.encoders)(db, a) for a in args ))
```

http://mysql-python.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/mysql-python/MySQLdb-2.0/diff/d9bb912776a5/MySQLdb/cursors.py#l1.144

Comment: could be, it's that connection literal that's triggering the error from what i can tell..

Comment: @user: naw, your source is 1.2.3, and you can see the line which raises exception in your original question posting. I think this diff is from newer source. yours is `query % connection.literal(args)`

Comment: It fails at the literal line but succeeds at string substitution, yet i chose 1.2.3 mysqldb as it said it was compatible with oyhtin 2.3.6.. are you saying the code looks like it isnt from 1.2.3?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQLdb 1.2.3, a query comes from string substitution using the first argument as the model string, and the second argument as a list of parameters or a single parameter, *passed through con.literal*. con.literal takes what you have supplied and tries to turn it into a string that gets parsed correctly by MySQL. It adds apostrophes to strings. It outputs numbers without quotes. Or for example, if you give it a string with an apostrophe, it quotes the apostrophe.

In your particular case, MySQLdb seems like it will always do the wrong thing when you hand it a tuple that has only one item in it (con is any open connection):

```
>>> con.literal((10,))
('10',)
>>>
```

That's what Python expects to be able to create a tuple with a single item in it, but it causes MySQL to barf (scroll right to see the barfness):

```
mysql> select distinct sites.SiteCode, sites.SiteName, Latitude, Longitude, County, SourceID from sites, seriescatalog where sites.SiteID = seriescatalog.SiteID and sites.SiteID in (82,);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
mysql>
```

This is my work-around to prevent Bobby Tabling:

```
siteinfoquery = """select distinct sites.SiteCode, sites.SiteName, Latitude, Longitude, County, SourceID from sites, seriescatalog where sites.SiteID = seriescatalog.SiteID and sites.SiteID in (%s);"""

cur.execute(siteinfoquery % ",".join([str(int(i)) for i in SiteID]))
```

BTW, the below doesn't work because con.literal (called inside MySQLdb's execute() function) quotes the resultant string, turning it from a list of numbers into a string, which then becomes a single value that doesn't match any SiteID:

```
cur.execute(siteinfoquery , ",".join([str(int(i)) for i in SiteID]))

>>> "(%s)" % con.literal(",".join([str(float(i)) for i in SiteID]))
"('10.0,20.0')"
>>>
```

I haven't looked to see if this is a bug fixed in a later version, a current issue, my bad, or a problem unknown to them.

Comment: Hrm. I seem to have read *my* problem as being the same as your problem. You're just trying to pass in a simple variable or two. Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem with MySQLdb 1.2.3, exactly what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this with MySQLdb. I'm using 1.2.2 final. 
Perhaps try a simple debug, to be sure that the problem is where you have indicated:

```
In [13]: cur.execute('select %s + %s', (1,2))
Out[13]: 1L

In [14]: cur.fetchall()
Out[14]: ((3L,),)
```

UPDATE 1: So I grabbed and installed 1.2.3 final, here's my transcript:

```
In [1]: import MySQLdb
In [2]: MySQLdb.version_info
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
In [3]: con = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='inventory')
In [4]: cur = con.cursor()
In [5]: cur.execute('select %s + %s', (1,2))
Out[5]: 1L
In [6]: cur.fetchall()
Out[6]: ((3L,),)
```

If only I could replicate your problem, then maybe I'd be able to offer a solution!?
So what else is different between our two environments?

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

UPDATE 2: 
You can perhaps break things down a little more than above. Note the following snippet from the source for MySQLdb-1.2.3:

```
139     def execute(self, query, args=None):
...
158         if args is not None:
159             query = query % db.literal(args)
160         try:
161             r = self._query(query)
162         except TypeError, m:
163             if m.args[0] in ("not enough arguments for format string",
164                              "not all arguments converted"):
165                 self.messages.append((ProgrammingError, m.args[0]))
```

line 159 is where your args are converted/escaped and then inserted into the query string. 
So perhaps you could do something like this:

```
In [24]: con.literal((1,2,))
Out[24]: ('1', '2')
```

To see how arguments are being converted by the driver, prior to merging with your query string.

```
In [26]: "select %s + %s" % con.literal((1,2,))
Out[26]: 'select 1 + 2'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to replicate with a similar version! Unfortunately same result, just fails out with no python error and no ouput of results

Comment: (I've also put in something to output exceptions: except MySQLdb.Error, e: dumpout.write("\n"+e.args[0]+" "+e.args[1]) but this isn't being output either..) ALTHOUGH my webserver has just put a log in again: the same "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" as above for the code you provided

Comment: try:
   c=db.cursor()
   c.execute('SELECT %s + %s', (1,2))
   sqlresults=c.fetchone()
   dumpout.write(str(sqlresults[0])) gives the same not enough arguments error, but it should know the tuple contains two, instead of the tuple itself being the only one..

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here, but get into the habit of using `repr()`, not `str()`, when getting debugging info.

Comment: @user...: I've updated above with 1.2.3 final (see Edit) and still can't replicate the issue. Surely we can find a way to protect you from Bobby'; Drop table ListsTable;!

Comment: Also, your error should be a python TypeError, thrown by line 159 in mysqldb. can you try a straight connection.literal((1,2,)) and show us the output? Cheers.

Comment: hm, looks like the same again, only happening there in main rather than the mysqldb lib: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "process.py", line 204, in ?
      main()
    File "process.py", line 91, in main
      sql='SELECT %s + %s'%db.literal((1,2))
  TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: so, the output from db.literal((1,2)) is (1,2) ? and your python setup can't do this: `"%s %s" % (1,2)` ?!

Comment: Hey guys, Still haven't solved this, but it seems to definitely be a problem with that db.literal line, anyone got any ideas? this :http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2006/12 looks like he's failing in the same area as me under the same conditions, but getting a different error..

Answer (score 0):

Working vs. non-working example:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
In [9]: conn = mysql.connect(host=hostname, user=user_name, passwd=password, port=port_number, db=schema_name)
In [10]: cursor = conn.cursor()
In [11]: cursor.execute('select %s + %s', (1, 3))
Out[11]: 1L

In [16]: conn = mysql.connect(host=hostname, user=user_name, passwd=password, port=port_number, db=schema_name, conv={FIELD_TYPE.LONG: long})
In [17]: cursor = conn.cursor()
In [18]: cursor.execute('select %s + %s', (1, 3))---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-08423fe5373f> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.execute('select %s + %s', (1, 3))
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
    156             query = query.encode(charset)
    157         if args is not None:
--> 158             query = query % db.literal(args)
    159         try:
    160             r = self._query(query)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The `conv` parameter to `mysql.connect` was the issue for me.  Without it, my query parameters are interpreted as expected.  With it, I was tearing my hair out.